# Stop a service so it can be uninstalled

Tags: powershell, service

I am doing some automated uninstalls of Autodesk software, and Autodesk has once again screwed the pooch with their uninstalls. Their uninstall is supposed to do reference counting on certain shared components, like their Single Signor Service, Autodesk Genuine Service, Licensing service, etc. The problem is, when you are uninstalling that last ADSK product, the uninstaller is too stupid to stop the service, so their uninstaller fails with a 1603 fatal error. Last year you could stop the services before you started the uninstall, but this year I am getting this error

```
Stop-Service : Service 'Autodesk Access Service Host (Autodesk Access Service Host)' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot open Autodesk Access Service Host service on computer '.'.
```

When using this code

```
Get-Service -Name "Autodesk Access Service Host" | Stop-Service -Force -NoWait
```

I have verified with

```
(Get-Service -Name "Autodesk Access Service Host").CanStop
```

that service can be stopped. At least according to the property.

I also tried

```
Start-Process "$env:WINDIR\system32\sc.exe" \\.,stop,"Autodesk Access Service Host" -NoNewWindow -Wait
while ((Get-Service -ComputerName '.' -Name "Autodesk Access Service Host" | 
Select -ExpandProperty Status) -ne 'Stopped') {
    Write-Host "Waiting for service to stop..."
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
}
```

And that has run for 15 minutes with no results. Interestingly I CAN disable the service, but I really don't want that. I just want to stop it temporarily, so IF the Autodesk uninstall that is running is the last one with a dependency on this service will uninstall it correctly and returns the correct exit code of 0.

EDIT: I tried

```
sc stop "Autodesk Access Service Host"
```

from an elevated command prompt and that shows

```
STATE              : 3  STOP_PENDING
(NOT_STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
```

so not really sure how to take `STOP_PENDING` along with `NOT_STOPPABLE`, nor why this would say NOT_STOPPABLE when the property above shows true.

Comment: If all else fails, you could try `Get-Process NameOfProcess | Stop-Process` to forcefully kill the process. Process may loose unsaved data, if that matters.

Comment: To see any potential errors (via the UI), temporarily edit the properties of the "Autodesk Access Service Host" service, go to the "Logon On" tab, and enable the "Allow service to interact with desktop".  Otherwise, ensure the service account has interactive logon rights to the system -- if not, a security Failure audit event should be generated in your Security event log if UI interaction is requested.  Personally, sounds like a dependent file (or service/port) may be locked, missing, or restricted.